# Get property type from setter on proxy class Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, runtime, setter, es6-proxy

I'm stuck in a problem. I'm creating a proxy for my BaseModel Class that have the base methods to interact with mongoose in a type way.

In my case I need get the type of the property to be setted to know what i need to do.
For this i use Reflect pattern.

```js
export enum ReflectKeys {

  /** Get the Typescript assigned Type at runtime */
  Type = 'design:type',

}

/**
 * A Proxy for all getters of model
 *
 * @export
 * @class Proxify
 */
export class Proxify {
  constructor() {
    return new Proxy(this, this);
  }

  public get(target: any, prop: string) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      // DO STUFFS
    }
  }

  set(target: any, prop: string, value: any, receiver: any): boolean {
    const type = Reflect.getOwnMetadata(ReflectKeys.Type, target, prop);

    console.log(type); // TYPE: UNDEFINED

    return target[prop] = value;
  }
}
```

When I console log the type that I was getting, the type is undefined! I don't know what i'm doing wrong.
This line of code where says Reflect I use that in another places and works fine.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Debug through your application or provide more information as to what `Reflect.getOwnMetadata()` does because it is returning `undefined`.

Comment: HI, yes. I'm using reflect-metadata package to get metadata from the class (https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata). When i going to get data from a children class of Proxy class, i have the Undefined type and not the type of the variable.
If there are another way to get the type of a variable from children class, it's work for me too.